# How to change git global user.email?

Tags: git

In my terminal if I run `git config --list` I get this list

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.email=someone@gmail.com.mm
user.name=someone
credential.email=
```

I want to replace `user.email` & `user.name`.
I also want to delete `credential.email`.

I already tried `git config --global user.email "email@example.com"` command but `user.email` does not replaced.

Comment: Try `git config --unset user.email` You may have a local setting that is overriding the global. If that does not work, add the `--global` tag to see if that helps

Comment: Note that `git config --list --show-origin` can be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git config --list` looks in the local repository config too. Any configuration defined in the repository overrides global configuration.

Unset the local repository configuration to allow the global configuration to take effect in this repository.

```
git config --unset user.email
```

Alternatively, set a new value for the local configuration.

```
git config user.email "email@example.com"
```